# Is there an application to generate Winform Code?

Tags: winforms, code-generation

I need a simple app to edit database tables.  Are there any code generators that will generate winforms in c#?  I have CodeSmith, are there any templates around that would help in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Management Studio.

Serious answer, .NetTiers for codesmith might help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I think [NConstruct](http://www.nconstruct.com/) might suit your needs - it generates Winforms (optionaly Web forms as well), you get full C# source code. You get application server based on [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) OR/M framework and client application which communicate with application server via .NET remoting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about .Net?  Have you looked at Visual Studio?  SharpDevelop also does this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DevExpress eXpressApp Framework](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/)

Comment: It's a bit pricey.  You need a Universal Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Rocket Framework it is free and you can find details at the hosted CodePlex site.. the link to Rocket Framework is below

http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/